# Parsing a large text file into chunks in Java

Tags: java, file, parsing, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I would like to receive some suggestions regarding a little problem I am going to solve in Java.

I have a file consisting in this format:

```
@
some text
some text
some text

@
some text
some text
some text

@
some text
some text
some text
```

...and so on.

I would need to read the next chunk of this text file, then to create an InputStream object consting of the read chunk and to pass the InputStream object to a parser. I have to repeat these operations for every chunk in the text file. Each chunk is written between the lines starting with @. The problem is to parse each section between the @ tags using a parser which should read each chunk from an InputStream.

The text file could be big, so I would like to obtain good performance.

How could I solve this problem?

I have thought about doing something like this:

```
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(bufferedReader);

    scanner.useDelimiter("@");

    List<ParsedChunk> parsedChunks = new ArrayList<ParsedChunk>();

    ChunkParser parser = new ChunkParser();

    while(scanner.hasNext())
    {
        String text = scanner.next();

        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        ParsedChunk parsedChunk = parser.parse(inputStream);

        parsedChunks.add(parsedChunk);

        inputStream.close();
    }

    scanner.close();
```

but I am not sure if it would be a good way to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: Hard to understand what exactly is the format of the file. Also, if you'd please use proper formatting markup in your post.

Comment: Before you start optimising you should measure what the problem is. In many systems the limiting fact is the time spent reading the file and splitting into lines. In that case you may be trying to speed up the fastest bit.

Comment: are downvoters need to pay from their wallet for giving reason?Why they dont leave a comment?

Comment: I have rewritten my post. Now it should be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly. This is what you are trying to achieve. FYI you will need JAVA  7 to get the below code running

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines(new File("d:/input.txt").toPath(), Charset.defaultCharset());
    List<List<String>> chunks = getChunks(allLines);
    //Now you have all te chunks and you can process them
}

private static List<List<String>> getChunks(List<String> allLines) {
    List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    int i = 0;
    int fromIndex = 1;
    int toIndex = 0;
    for(String line : allLines){
        i++;
        if(line.startsWith("****") && i != 1){ // To skip the first line and the check next delimiter
            toIndex = i-1;          
            result.add(allLines.subList(fromIndex, toIndex));
            fromIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

didnt quite get the question but u could try using char at this moment as, storing all the character in char array & going thhrough a loop & condiional statement which breaks the string every time it encounters a'@'